# Request an extension for revision for a second time

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission, authorship

Is it normal to request an extension for the revised version of the article for the second time?

I have a manuscript submitted to a journal, and although I have requested an extension for two weeks, it is very unlikely that the final version of the manuscript will be ready by then.

Comment: What do you mean by "the final version of the menus will be ready by then"?

Comment: @Christian Possibly a typo for "manuscript", but not sure.

Comment: This is quite unusual. If the necessary revisions are so substantial that you can't do them in the allotted time even with two weeks extension (you are making this a priority, right?), you can ask for another extension but should probably withdraw for now and resubmit later. Asking for multiple extensions is not normal.

Comment: @GoogDeeds Yes. I mean "manuscript".

Comment: Thank you @Ronald.

Answer (score 4):

You are interfering with the normal workflow of the editor and your referees.  We all understand that life happens, but you should not be surprised if your request is denied, or some odd situation arises, like a previous referee refuses to look at your manuscript again, necessitating new review, where anything can happen.

There's also the possibility, especially if such requests become a habit with you, that your community may start to view you as hard to work with.  This is a reputation you don't need.

Comment: Thankful. Your explanation was complete and realistic.